# New Roles and Capabilities in WordPress

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I am creating a new role in WordPress, and I would like it to be simlar to an 'author' role, except that this new role only allows 'working with' a specific category (in other words, it allows editing, posting, deleting posts of a specific category only).

Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create a new role and enable specific capabilities.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I already know how to add a role and add capabilities to it; but how can I limit the capability to a specific category. Assume I have two categories, CAT-A and CAT-B, and I want to limit the capabilities of the new role to only work with CAT-B, how can I do that?

Comment: I have the same question. I was directed here. Seems like there are a bunch of people asking the same question.