# Letting users create a post that is a custom post type from a page

Tags: user-roles

I'm trying to create a kind of "Request for Proposals" system for a blog that belongs to a client of mine.

I'm not too sure how to go about this, but so far I've outlined this much..

I know there will be two kinds of users for this. 
1. Proposers
2. Speculators

Proposers will be able to submit their proposals from the front-end of the site.

Speculators will be able to login and see the page that lists all the most recent proposals, as well as view them individually. Speculators should be the only role allowed to do this.

Now, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create these two user types.

I can see in Press Permit videos that he's got user roles like "Student" and a few others. But there isn't any video that shows how he was able to create those users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new role and name it anything you like.

Then you can add any type of capability you like

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129807/9884

Comment: Check that out. Seems like it's not complete for what I'm looking for. I need to allow the new role to be able to see the private category I create.